# ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed--keeps on appearing on my Windows Form App c#?

Tags: c#

I am new in programming and i really don't know what to do with this one... you see that message keeps on appearing. I am trying to make a program with when you click the button it saves the username in a table but the username should be valid first. here's my code...

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\HP\Documents\main.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select count(*) from users where username ='" + textBox1.Text + "' and password='" + textBox2.Text + "'", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("ULogin", conn);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", textBox1.Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid username and password.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
    void Clear()
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox2.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: btw; your approach to sql is incredibly dangerous - you have a SQL injection hole *and* a plain text password; this is an **incredibly** dangerous combination that can lead to data loss and data theft. I'm talking about the concatenated code in `sda`

Comment: you might find tools like "dapper" useful - it takes away all the pain of ADO.NET, just letting you focus on what you're actually trying to do - the SQL, inputs, and outputs

Answer (score 1):

In between the following lines  you need to  open the database connection which currently you are not doing:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 conn.Open(); // add this before the Fill call
 sda.Fill(dt);
```

and you will also need to close the connection after that by doing:

```
conn.close();
```

a more better way would be to use `using` block so that connection is closed automatically when  the code reaches out the block:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\HP\Documents\main.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
{
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select count(*) from users where username ='" + textBox1.Text + "' and password='" + textBox2.Text + "'", conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    conn.Open();
    sda.Fill(dt);
}
```

One more thing is in the next block  you are missing the `{ }` of `using` block, that code should be adjusted to:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("ULogin", sqlCon);
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", textBox1.Text.Trim());
    sqlCon.Open();
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Clear();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The command in the last block is using the wrong connection. Was like that in OP as well.

Answer (score 0):

To give a clear answer to your problem. You use the wrong SqlConnection in your SqlCommand construction:

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("ULogin", conn);
```

Should be:

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("ULogin", sqlCon);
```